# How to get user specific information from content database in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell, sql

I am using SharePoint 2010. I want to know the user specific details i.e. when and by whom a specific user was given permission to the site. My audit logs are disabled in CA.Is it possible to get the information from content database? If yes please let me know how?

Comment: If auditing is disabled, no, you aren't going to be able to determine that

Comment: This is information is not in content database / sharepoint API.

Comment: okay...so ultimately there is no way to get this information?

Answer (score 0):

We can get the user specific details from content database from the table named `EventLog` even if the audit logs are disabled in CA provided that the records are still present in the table. (usually the record are cleared from the table at regular intervals)